# How to programmatically find a menu item which an article is assigned to in Joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

In Joomla 2.5, based on an article id, how to programmatically find related menu item which has this article assigned to?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For what purpose will you need the article id, and in what context? Depending on the purpose, there might be other ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm...that might get messy.  Unless there's a simpler solution something like this will get you started (tested and it works):

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->SELECT('
    menu.id AS id
    ,menu.link AS link');
$query->FROM('#__menu AS menu');
$query->GROUP('
     menu.id
     ,menu.link');
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadAssocList();

//take the results, loop, explode the link apart to isolate the article id
foreach ($results as &$result) {
    $articleid = explode('view=article&id=', $result[link]);
    echo $result[id] . " - " . $articleid[1] . "<br />";
}
```